# How to write a method in controller which calls before loading particular partial on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, partial-views

I need to do execute set of lines before the partial load in my Rails project so I need to call specific method which I can declare In controller. So how can I do this??

Please give your ideas to solve this problem.

Comment: As worded the question is difficult to answer. If you need to "do some stuff" before you load a partial, write and call a method that does the stuff.